# How to decrease number of queries to DB?

Tags: django, django-orm

I have a model like

```
class Node(BaseModel, NodeContent):
    __metaclass__ = NodeMetaClass

    node_type  = models.CharField(max_length=16, default='node')
    abs_parent = models.ForeignKey('Node', related_name='all_children', null=True)
... # a lot of other fields
```

and a code like this

```
nodes = Node.objects.filter(node_type='comment')
for node in nodes:
    t = node.abs_parent.title
```

It works but an additional query is executed for each node. I tried to add select_related:

```
nodes = Node.objects.select_related('abs_parent').filter(node_type='comment')
```

but this doesn't help. What am I doing wrong?

**Upd:** @SColvin, thank you for the great method, it works! But actually one field is not enough for me. I'm trying to provide the code that will process nodes further with already loaded .abs_parent objects. This code is already written and awaits interface like node.abs_parent. (maybe with further following through foreign keys). I'm working with the OSQA engine and I'm trying to speed-up it.

Comment: You should be able to get more than one field suing values_list. Also, a useful tool for identifying SQL usage is the awesome django-debug-toolbar: http://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: I checked debug toolbar: it was already used in the code, but wasn't installed. I installed it but got 

    ImportError: cannot import name force_text


on from django.utils.encoding import force_text. I think I can live without it since I already know how to log raw SQL queries

Answer (score 2):

I haven't got Django here, so I can't test it, but you should be able to use

```
node = Node.objects.filter(node_type='comment')
node_titles = nodes.values_list('abs_parent__title', flat=True)
```

See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list)

(Note: I assume since this is the "Djangotronic" way of doing things it should query the db a minimal number of times, but I don't know for sure.)